# Magento 2.3.0 Composer Fatal error when installing

Tags: magento2

Trying to install anything on Magento 2.3.0 using Composer I get the following error.

anyone know how to fix this?

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of
> Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin_composer_tmp1::initModuleDeployment()
> must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void, none
> returned in
> phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(195)
> : eval()'d code:69 Stack trace:
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused due to PHP compatibility.

Check PHP version, it may require to upgrade/downgrade PHP version depending on [Magento 2.3 requirements.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php)